# Splitting to make Workbooks

Tags: python, dataframe

If I have a column that is called `Name` and in this column I have names like umbrella corp, umbrella inc, umbrella llc I dont want to loop through this column and make a workbook from unique because I would get three seperate workbooks.

So is their a way to split them at the first space and then make workbooks for unique?

So could I do `df['Name'].str.split(' ', 1)` which is saying split at first occurrence.

I then want to make workbooks for the split occurrence so for umbrella corp I would just be making a workbook from the first split which would be umbrella. So instead of making multiple workbooks I would just have one that brings all 3 of the names that have umbrella as the first split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new column that only has the first part of the name and loop thru that column:

```
df['newColumn'] = df.brand_name.apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0])
```

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that the dtype is object, so when I try this exmaple I get 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: it is possible that you could cast it as a string in the lambda function via  `str(x).split(' ')[0]`

Comment: It worked thank you I never thought to create a new column. Thank you!